# Page with the same name of a category

Tags: categories, pages, urls

I've a *category*, let's say "testcat". I want to create some *pages* which the final url should be "http://example.com/testcat/pagename". To do this, I should create a *page* named "testcat" and then a page named "pagename" with the *page* "testcat" as parent page. I tried and it seemd to work, but I'm worried about what's happening in the backend as actually there should be TWO pages on the same url http://example.com/testcat/: the default category page for "testcat" *category* and my *custom page* "testcat".

Could you help me to understand if this is the right way to do what I want, or should I use another method? Thanks.

Comment: The default behavior of wordpress for the categories is http://example.com/category/testcat so unless you haven't change the permalink structure you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: I've removed /category/ from url.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it but you need 301 Redirect category to Page with Follow links

that is good for SEO ? links jus from category going to the page

i make it for my sell landing page , because i don't need my visiter  going to

category page what you need to do for example

http://example.com/testcat/pagename 301 to http://example.com/testcat/ with

Follow if you have seo plugin by yoast